# Creating a condition on Email Replied to stop a PowerAutomate process and that the automation to continue if email is not replied

Tags: power-automate

I have a workflow in PowerAutomate that has three emails. If the first email has been replied to, I need the automation to stop sending the next two - second and third emails. Also, if the second email has been replied to, I need the automation to stop sending third email.

I am fetching the information of clients to send these emails to from an online Excel workbook.

I have the workflow running but I need help in creating the two conditions that will limit sending of the emails once the email is replied to.

I tried using a condition but I do not understand because I am limited in my knowledge.

Comment: Are you using PAD or PA cloud flows?  There's a major difference so please only include a single tag.

Comment: I am using PA cloud